# Visual Basic error BC30456 'ExecuteNonQuery' is not a member of 'OleDbCommand'

Tags: vb.net

Visual Basic error BC30456 'ExecuteNonQuery' is not a member of 'OleDbCommand'.

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Below is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmProgram

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub cbocourse_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocourse.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub cbocourse_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles cbocourse.KeyPress
        e.Handled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
        Try
            If MsgBox("SAVE RECORD?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
                ' Your saving logic here.
            End If
            cn.Open()
            cm = New OleDbCommand("insert into tblProgram(Sec_code, description, course) values(@Sec_code, @description, @course)", cn)
            With cm
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sec_code", txtsec_code.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtdescription.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", cbocourse.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            cn.Close()
            MsgBox("RECORD HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY SAVED", vbInformation)
        Catch ex As Exception
            cn.Close()
            MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub Clear()
        txtdescription.Clear()
        txtsec_code.Clear()
        txtsec_code.Enabled = True
        btnsave.Enabled = True
        btnupdate.Enabled = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That is very strange. If you comment out the namespace import at the top of that code, what happens? Do you get an error message indicating that the `OleDbCommand` type is not defined?

Comment: Where are `cn` and `cm` declared? Why are they not declared right there in the code that uses them? Use local variables for your ADO.NET objects. You seem to be using variables that are not even declared in the current type. That's a misuse of ADO.NET.

Comment: [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#returns) returns a value that indicates the number of rows that were successfully inserted. How do you expect to know whether or not the insert was successful without the return value?

Comment: @user246821, I don't think that's relevant in this case, given that it's an insert. That may be relevant when updating or deleting, because you might want to know how many records matched your filter. In the case of an insert, it will either succeed or it will throw an exception. I'm not aware of any scenario where `ExecuteNonQuery` could return zero for an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: BTW, you should not be calling `cn.Close` in both the `Try` and `Catch` blocks. Ideally, you would be creating the connection object where you use it, in which case you would use a `Using` block to both create and dispose the object. Disposal includes closing. If you're determined not to do that, you should have a `Finally` block and put any code that needs to be executed whether or not an exception is thrown in there. By putting that code in a `Finally` block only, you adhere to the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: One should develop good programming practices, as well as, follow common conventions/standards. Failure to do so, makes it difficult for others who may be tasked with maintaining the code. Also, it makes one's post less likely to receive responses on SO.

Comment: @user246821, *"How do you expect to know whether or not the insert was successful without the return value?"*. Because an exception will be thrown and the OP is catching it, so they are following good practice from that perspective. You seem to be suggesting that they should write extra code that cannot make any difference to the result. Not sure I'd call that good practice. If this were C# then perhaps using a discard for that result would be a good idea, to explicitly show that there is a result that is not used, but if there's no point using it, I'd say don't use it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: _You seem to be suggesting that they should write extra code that cannot make any difference to the result._: Absolutely. I believe that one should write code in a manner that is easy to understand and easy to debug even if it means it's more verbose. I also insist that others chew with his/her/their mouth closed.